# How to add a confirm box when click on a botton, Python/html script

Tags: python, html, confirm

I need to add a confirm box when I click on logout or restart buttons in my following python/html script. This script is just summary of large one and its work fine with me.any suggestion please?

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cherrypy
import os.path
import struct
from auth import AuthController, require, member_of, name_is
import subprocess
import commands

class Server(object):
    led_logout=0 
    led_restart=0
    _cp_config = {
    'tools.sessions.on': True,
    'tools.auth.on': True
    }   
    auth = AuthController()      
    @cherrypy.expose
    @require()
    def index(self,logout='', restart=''):

    html = """
     <html>
      <head>
      </head>
          <body>
        <p>{htmlText} 
        <p>
        <a href="?logout=1"><img src="images/Logout.png"><a href="?restart=1"><img src="images/Restart.png"></a>
        </ul>
          </body>
     </html>    
           """
    myText = ''
    myText = "Hello"

    if logout:
        self.led_logout = int(logout)             
    if self.led_logout:
        print "Logout !!!!!"
        AuthController().logout('/?logout=0')

    if restart:
        self.led_restart = int(restart)
        #subprocess.call(['sudo shutdown -r now'], shell=True)
        myText = "The system is restarting"

    return html.format(htmlText=myText)
    index.exposed = True

#configuration
conf = {
    'global' : { 
        'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0', #0.0.0.0 or specific IP
        'server.socket_port': 8085 #server port
    },

    '/images': { #images served as static files
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': os.path.abspath('/home/ubuntu/webserver/images')
    }
    }
cherrypy.quickstart(Server(), config=conf)
```

Comment: You need to use javascript for this; as the button will only show up on the browser side.

Comment: OK, can you please show an example so that I can added to my script?

Answer (score 1):

OK I got the solution, I just added

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?');"
```

So the complete line will be:

```
<a href="?logout=1" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?');"><img src="images/Logout.png"><a href="?restart=1" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to restart?');" ><img src="images/Restart.png"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot the `return` statement insite the `onclick` attribute!